# Unable to install packages correctly in docker

Tags: node.js, docker, npm

I was able to install all packages with npm, but two days ago I'm getting this error.

```
Step 8/12 : RUN npm install
 ---> Running in aedc04c5281e

> sharp@0.25.4 install /home/project/website/node_modules/sharp
> (node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install --runtime=napi) || (node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)

info sharp Downloading https://github.com/lovell/sharp-libvips/releases/download/v8.9.1/libvips-8.9.1-linuxmusl-x64.tar.gz

> cwebp-bin@5.1.0 postinstall /home/project/website/node_modules/cwebp-bin
> node lib/install.js

  ⚠ spawn /home/project/website/node_modules/cwebp-bin/vendor/cwebp ENOENT
  ⚠ cwebp pre-build test failed
  ℹ compiling from source
...
```

Here is my docker file

```
FROM node:12-alpine

RUN apk add --no-cache build-base gcc autoconf automake libtool zlib-dev libpng-dev nasm

RUN mkdir -p /home/project/website/node_modules && chown -R node:node /home/project/website

WORKDIR /home/project/website

COPY /package*.json ./

USER node

RUN npm cache verify

RUN npm install

COPY --chown=node:node . .

RUN chmod +x wait-for.sh

RUN chmod -R 0755 /home/project/website/src/views/

EXPOSE 8080
```

after the building completed I get this in logs

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:968
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/home/project/website/node_modules/.bin/nodemon'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:965:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:841:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

and after I run this following cmd
`docker-compose run website sh -c "npm list --depth=0"`
I get this

```
+-- UNMET DEPENDENCY bcryptjs@2.4.3
+-- UNMET DEPENDENCY compression@1.7.4
| +-- accepts@1.3.7
| +-- bytes@3.0.0
| +-- compressible@2.0.18
| +-- debug@2.6.9
| +-- on-headers@1.0.2
| +-- safe-buffer@5.1.2
| `-- vary@1.1.2
+-- UNMET DEPENDENCY cors@2.8.5
| +-- object-assign@4.1.1
| `-- vary@1.1.2
+-- UNMET DEPENDENCY dateformat@3.0.3
+-- UNMET DEPENDENCY dotenv@8.2.0
+-- UNMET DEPENDENCY ejs@3.1.5
| `-- jake@10.8.2
+-- UNMET DEPENDENCY express@4.17.1
...
```

and my packages are

```
{
  "name": "website",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon src/app.js"
  },
  "author": "Noah Lc",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "compression": "^1.7.4",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dateformat": "^3.0.3",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "ejs": "^3.1.3",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "helmet": "^4.1.1",
    "image-size": "^0.8.3",
    "imagemin": "^7.0.1",
    "imagemin-mozjpeg": "^9.0.0",
    "imagemin-webp": "^6.0.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.7.7",
    "multer": "^1.4.2",
    "nodemailer": "^6.4.11",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.3",
    "sharp": "^0.25.4",
    "sitemap": "^6.2.0",
    "slugify": "^1.4.0",
    "superagent": "^5.2.2",
    "validator": "^12.0.0",
    "winston": "^3.3.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {}
}
```

Are there any clean ways to skip pre and post-build steps of those dips in the plugin itself to avoid any issues in the containerized environment?

Comment: I don't see any error in the logs you included, just a module compiling because there was no prebuild binary

Comment: Hi, I have updated my question. you can take a look again.

Comment: Can you include your package.json file ?

Comment: I have done @Seblor

Answer (score 0):

```
RUN apk add --no-cache \
--update \
build-base \
mesa-dev \
gcc \
autoconf \
automake \
libtool \
zlib-dev \
nasm \
mesa \
libxi \
libpng-dev \
libjpeg \
jpeg-dev
```

Comment: It worked for me, but maybe there is something extra.

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I am just answering stackoverflow for the first time. In the future, I will avoid this error.

Comment: Why not avoid it now and improve this answer as well?